# yii ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller page not loading when scroll in the popup window

Tags: php, yii, infinite-scroll, yii-extensions

I am using yii ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller for paging. It is working correctly in the normal page and listed correctly. If we use the same code in the popup window, first 12 rows are displayed. if i scroll in the popup, next page is not loading.only displays 12 rows

Here is the controller page coding

```
//get criteria
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = '"Region"=:Region AND tasting_room AND "Latitude" IS NOT NULL AND NOT "DOW_open"[:DOW] IS NULL'.$qr;
            $criteria->params = $psdarr;
//get row_count
            $row_count = Wineries::model()->count($criteria);

            //pagination
            $pages = new CPagination($row_count);
            $pages->setPageSize(12);
            $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

            $Wineries = Wineries::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Here is the view page coding

```
$this->widget('ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller', array(
                    'contentSelector' => '#winerycontainer',
                    'itemSelector' => 'ul.wlist',
                    'loadingText' => 'Loading next 12 rows...',
                    'donetext' => 'Loading finish.',
                    'pages' => $pages,
                    ));
```

How can i fix that page loading problem in popup window? Pls help me anybody knows

Comment: check your console, see where the GET request is going

Comment: sorry tinybyte, what you say. i couldn't understand. Pls explain in detail

Comment: Yii::log("Pagination Wineries row_count = $row_count page # = " . $pages->getCurrentPage(), 'error', 'actionSelectwineries.end');
Yii::log("Pagination Wineries GET = " . CVarDumper::dumpAsString($_GET), 'error', 'actionSelectwineries.end');